# Displaying current time in JS w/ given functions

Tags: javascript, time

Need to display current time in JS with the given functions.

Internet searches showed JS using Date() and Time() for gathering the info, but the date and time are not showing up in the HTML when run it.

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var displayCurrentTime = function() {
    var now = new Date();  //use the 'now' variable in all calculations, etc.
    var Date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    var hours = now.getHours()+ ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" 
    + now.getSeconds();

    //Ok, problem now is getting HTML to call it up?
};

var padSingleDigit = function(num) {
    if (num < 10) { return "0" + num; }
    else { return num; }
};

window.onload = function() {
    // set initial clock display and then set interval timer to display
    // new time every second. Don't store timer object because it
    // won't be needed - clock will just run.

};
```

Instructor's instructions:

"Note that to convert the computer’s time from a 24-hour clock to a 12-hour clock, first check to see if the hours value is greater than 12. If so, subtract 12 from the hours value and set the AM/PM value to “PM”. Also, be aware that the hours value for midnight is 0.

The starter project has four functions supplied: the $ function, the start of a displayCurrentTime() function, a padSingleDigit() function that adds a leading zero to single digits, and the start of an onload event handler.

In the displayCurrentTime() function, add code that uses the Date object to determine the current hour, minute, and second. Convert these values to a 12hour clock, determine the AM/PM value, and display these values in the appropriate span tags.

Then, in the onload event handler, code a timer that calls the displayCurrentTime() function at 1 second intervals. Also, make sure that the current time shows as soon as the page loads. (some comments have been included in the starter code to guide you on where to place things)."

Comment: `var Date =  ...` — you'll need to pick a different variable name.

Comment: Nothing is happening because your `window.onload` function is empty.

Comment: You've got to set up your HTML. Give it some unique `id`, then call `document.getElementById` on it, and change its `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

In order to grap an html element you first need one. So i made a tag with an id of "clock". I then set an interval, running every 1000 milis (1 second) to give me the correctly formatted time.

```js
clock = document.getElementById("clock");
let hours, minutes, seconds;

function checkDigits(num, hours) {
  if (num < 10) {
    return "0" + num
  } else {
    if (hours) {
      return num - 12
    }
    return num
  }
}

function updateTime() {
  date = new Date();
  hours = checkDigits(date.getHours(), true)
  minutes = checkDigits(date.getMinutes())
  seconds = checkDigits(date.getSeconds())
  clock.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    updateTime()
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="clock"></h1>
```

Comment: Ok, I got that code part in, no problem, but it keeps returning an error message saying "the global variable clock is undefined." Here's the HTML I'm using

````<html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Clock</title><link rel="stylesheet"href="clock.css"><script src="clock.js"></script></head><body><main><h1 id="clock"></h1><fieldset><legend>Clock</legend>            <span id="hours">&nbsp;</span>:
            <span id="minutes">&nbsp;</span>:
            <span id="seconds">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
            <span id="ampm">&nbsp;</span>
        </fieldset>
    </main>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Mike two things, you didnt format the code so it gave me a severe illness to read it. And second, youre using 3 different spans for each variable (hours seconds minutes), you would need to do document.getElementById() for each of those span tags and set their values, or do as im doing and use 1 tag thats being fed a string. If you need further help Ill update my code to work with 3 spans tags for example.